# Quotient of Flag varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, flag-varieties

Let $G=SL_3(\mathbb{C})$ and $X=G/B$ be the associated full flag variety. Fix a non-degenerate symmetric quadratic form $Q$ on $\mathbb{C}^3$. This gives an order $2$ automorphism $F_Q$ of $X$, mapping a flag $(L,P)$ to $(P^{\perp},L^{\perp})$. Is there any explicit description of the quotient $X/F_Q$  ?

Comment: Take a look at Danny Gillam's thesis, in particular http://arxiv.org/abs/0708.0842.  He verifies the Crepant Resolution Conjecture for this orbifold.

Comment: @Dave: This seems to be most relevant to the question.    It may be useful to cite the published version, though it's hard for most people to access and may not differ from the preprint: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3011793

Comment: I had a look at the paper. It proves many properties of the quotient, but it does not give any explicit description. Moreover, it mainly focus on the case where the quadratic form is degenerate, so that the involution has fixed points and the quotient is singular; I am more interested in the other case. I wonder if there is something in term of classical representation theory, or in term of some Grassmannian

Comment: Why is this fixed-point free? Can't $L= P^{\perp}$ if $L$ is isotropic? I think the fixed points form a flag variety of $SO(3)_Q$ - a $\mathbb P^1$.

Comment: you are right! sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's coordinatize $G/B = Proj\ \mathbb C[m_{11}\ldots m_{33}]/\langle trace=0, rank \leq 1\rangle$, with $F_Q(M) = M^T$, the image of $(L,P) \mapsto L P^T$ (a column vector times row vector).

Then the $F_Q$-invariants are generated by $n_i := m_{ii}, q_{i < j} := m_{ij}m_{ji}, s_{i < j} := s_{ij}s_{ji}$. They satisfy
$${n}_{1}+{n}_{2}+{n}_{3}, \qquad
{p}_{12} {p}_{13}+{p}_{12} {p}_{23}+{p}_{13} {p}_{23},\qquad
{n}_{2} {p}_{13}+{n}_{2} {p}_{23}+{n}_{3} {p}_{23}$$
$${n}_{3} {p}_{12}+{n}_{2} {p}_{23}+{n}_{3} {p}_{23},\qquad {n}_{3}^{2}+{p}_{13}+{p}_{23},\qquad {n}_{2} {n}_{3}-{p}_{23},\qquad {n}_{2}^{2}+{p}_{12}+{p}_{23}$$
$${n}_{3} {s}_{12}^{2}+{n}_{2} {s}_{13}^{2}-{s}_{12} {s}_{13} {s}_{23}-{n}_{2} {s}_{23}^{2}-{n}_{3} {s}_{23}^{2}+4 {n}_{2} {p}_{23}+4 {n}_{3} {p}_{23}$$
$${n}_{3} {s}_{12} {s}_{13} {s}_{23}+{p}_{13} {s}_{12}^{2}+{p}_{23} {s}_{12}^{2}-{p}_{23} {s}_{13}^{2}-{p}_{13} {s}_{23}^{2}+4 {p}_{13} {p}_{23}$$
$${n}_{2} {s}_{12} {s}_{13} {s}_{23}-{p}_{23} {s}_{12}^{2}+{p}_{12} {s}_{13}^{2}+{p}_{23} {s}_{13}^{2}-{p}_{12} {s}_{23}^{2}+4 {p}_{12} {p}_{23}$$
$${n}_{2} {p}_{23} {s}_{12}^{2}-{n}_{2} {p}_{12} {s}_{13}^{2}-{n}_{2} {p}_{23} {s}_{13}^{2}+{p}_{12} {s}_{12} {s}_{13} {s}_{23}+{p}_{23} {s}_{12} {s}_{13} {s}_{23}+{n}_{2} {p}_{12} {s}_{23}^{2}-4 {n}_{2} {p}_{12} {p}_{23}$$
$${n}_{2} {s}_{13}^{3} {s}_{23}-{s}_{12} {s}_{13}^{2} {s}_{23}^{2}-{n}_{2} {s}_{13} {s}_{23}^{3}-{n}_{3} {s}_{13} {s}_{23}^{3}-{p}_{13} {s}_{12}^{3}-{p}_{23} {s}_{12}^{3}+{p}_{23} {s}_{12} {s}_{13}^{2}+4 {n}_{2} {p}_{23} {s}_{13} {s}_{23}+4 {n}_{3} {p}_{23} {s}_{13} {s}_{23}+{p}_{13} {s}_{12} {s}_{23}^{2}-4 {p}_{13} {p}_{23} {s}_{12}$$
$${s}_{12}^{2} {s}_{13}^{2} {s}_{23}^{2}+{p}_{13} {s}_{12}^{4}+{p}_{23} {s}_{12}^{4}-2 {p}_{23} {s}_{12}^{2} {s}_{13}^{2}+{p}_{12} {s}_{13}^{4}+{p}_{23} {s}_{13}^{4}-2 {p}_{13} {s}_{12}^{2} {s}_{23}^{2}-2 {p}_{12} {s}_{13}^{2} {s}_{23}^{2}+{p}_{12} {s}_{23}^{4}+{p}_{13} {s}_{23}^{4}+8 {p}_{13} {p}_{23} {s}_{12}^{2}+8 {p}_{12} {p}_{23} {s}_{13}^{2}-8 {p}_{12} {p}_{23} {s}_{23}^{2}-8 {p}_{13} {p}_{23} {s}_{23}^{2}+16 {p}_{12} {p}_{23}^{2}+16 {p}_{13} {p}_{23}^{2}$$
$${n}_{3} {p}_{23} {s}_{13}^{3} {s}_{23}+{p}_{13} {s}_{12} {s}_{13}^{2} {s}_{23}^{2}+{p}_{23} {s}_{12} {s}_{13}^{2} {s}_{23}^{2}+{n}_{3} {p}_{13} {s}_{13} {s}_{23}^{3}+{p}_{13}^{2} {s}_{12}^{3}+2 {p}_{13} {p}_{23} {s}_{12}^{3}+{p}_{23}^{2} {s}_{12}^{3}-{p}_{13} {p}_{23} {s}_{12} {s}_{13}^{2}-{p}_{23}^{2} {s}_{12} {s}_{13}^{2}-4 {n}_{3} {p}_{13} {p}_{23} {s}_{13} {s}_{23}-{p}_{13}^{2} {s}_{12} {s}_{23}^{2}-{p}_{13} {p}_{23} {s}_{12} {s}_{23}^{2}+4 {p}_{13}^{2} {p}_{23} {s}_{12}+4 {p}_{13} {p}_{23}^{2} {s}_{12}$$
a quick, if useless, Macaulay 2 computation:

```
R = QQ[m_(1,1)..m_(3,3)]
M = matrix apply(3,i->apply(3,j->(m_(i+1,j+1))))
I = ideal trace M + ideal exteriorPower(2,M)
S = QQ[n_1..n_3, p_(1,2), p_(1,3), p_(2,3), s_(1,2), s_(1,3), s_(2,3)]

f = map(R/I,S, {m_(1,1),m_(2,2),m_(3,3), 
m_(1,2)*m_(2,1), m_(1,3)*m_(3,1), m_(2,3)*m_(3,2), 
m_(1,2)+m_(2,1), m_(1,3)+m_(3,1), m_(2,3)+m_(3,2)})
ker f
```

Comment: thanks! Do you think something more intrinsic (=without equations) is possible? Or it is just a random smooth Picard rank one Fano 3fold?